# How clients can Launch (redirected to) an ASP.NET website automatically on a local web server (Windows) by just connecting the router or acceess point

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, web, c#-4.0

I have a restaurant , I have a website written in ASP.NET on a local web server (windows) in a local network. what I want is my customers when they connect to a router or access point , my website is automatically launch. how can I do that ???